# $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ Borel-measurable function: What does that mean?

Tags: measure-theory

A basic question:

If I have a Borel-measurable function $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, what is meant with that?

Does this mean $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})_{|[a,b]}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, where
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})_{|[a,b]}=\left\{[a,b]\cap B: B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\}?
$$

Comment: Yes, you can put it like that.

Comment: Is there another way? :-)

Comment: This is the definition. There's not much more to say to it.

Comment: OK, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

f is borel measurable if the set $$\left\{x \in [a,b] : f(x) <t \right\} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$ $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

Thats another way of looking at it

Comment: And, indeed, it is a better way.  Since this is also used to define $\mathcal F$-measurable for a function from a measure space $(X, \mathcal F, \mu)$ to $\mathbb R$.